# Unite search results from different tables in page split output

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, design-patterns

I have 3 entities and each has a corresponding table.  I have a task to search in these 3 tables so results will be shown at one page, mixing together according to sort conditions. I am looking for a proper solution.  I have some ideas.

It's possible to perform 3 search queries for each table and then show the results in consideration of sort conditions.  It is simple when I have the search results all on one page.  When I need to split results to pages, I can use the following algorithm:  I run the same 3 search queries and I save result rows IDs and table names in session for current search in the necessary sort order.  I perform these queries only once at search start.
According to the selected page I will find IDs in session and perform 3 simple queries to find rows by their IDs.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem better? 
I do it on the MySQL+PHP+Zend framework base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic way of doing this. For this example, each table has an 'id' and a 'timestamp' field, and we want to sort the results by the timestamp field.

```
<?
function bubblesort(array $items) {
    // Sorts the items in a two-dimensional array based on a
    // timestamp in the first field of the arrays passed.
    do{
        $flag = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < (count($items) - 1); $i++) {
            if(strtotime($items[$i][0]) > strtotime($items[$i + 1][0])) {
                $swap = $items[$i];
                $items[$i] = $items[$i + 1];
                $items[$i + 1] = $swap;

                $flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while($flag);
    return $items;
}
$results = array();

// Get results for the first table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `id` FROM `table1`;");
if (!$result)
    die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $results[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);

// Get results for the second table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `id` FROM `table2`;");
if (!$result)
    die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $results[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);

// Get results for the third table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `id` FROM `table3`;");
if (!$result)
    die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $results[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);

// Sort the joint results
$results = bubblesort($results);
?>
```

Of course, each of the queries will have to be adapted for the individual table. Note that I've used a bubble sort alogrithm, depending on the amount of results you're expecting, a different sorting algorithm might be better.

It may also be better to merge the three SELECT queries into one by using UNION (see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)), but I don't know enough about the structure of the tables to tell you the query you'd need.

Comment: Yes, you describe same to my algorithm for no splitted to pages results. My task is more complicated and I looking for different approaches to solve.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. After rereading it I cannot think of a better way to do it than what you have at the moment.